# Python - Only call a certain part once until input changes

Tags: python

So i use a raspberry pi to turn on a Hue light while the door is open, then turn it off.

So far i checked every 0.5 Seconds wheter or not the door is open, and then called hue to turn on or off the lights.

What i want to do is check if the door is open or closed more frequent (like 0.1 seconds or something) and only call the hue lights whenever the status of the Door changes, so that Hue does not get called every 0.1 seconds, but only if it actually has to change something.

This is my Code so far:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #import the GPIO library
import time
import requests

from phue import Bridge

b = Bridge('?')
b.get_api()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


print("Hello")

while True:
    if GPIO.input(20):
       print("Door is closed")
       b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
       b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', 'on', False)
       time.sleep(0.5)
    if GPIO.input(20) == False:
       print("Door is open")
       b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
       command =  {'transitiontime' : 0, 'on' : True, 'bri' : 254}
       b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', command)
       time.sleep(2)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just store the previous state is a variable and test whether a change occured. If no just do nothing (too lazy to write an answer with that, feel free to use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the state of the door and call the light only if it has changed.

```py
...

state = True

while True:
    if GPIO.input(20) != state:
        state = GPIO.input(20)
        if GPIO.input(20):
            print("Door is closed")
            b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
            b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', 'on', False)
        else:
            print("Door is open")
            b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
            command =  {'transitiontime' : 0, 'on' : True, 'bri' : 254}
            b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', command)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the first response, this might not be beautiful but should work.

```
state = None
oldstate = None

while True:
    if GPIO.input(20):
       print("Door is closed")
       state = "closed"
       if state != oldestate:
            b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
            b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', 'on', False)
       oldstate = "closed"
       time.sleep(0.5)
    if GPIO.input(20) == False:
       print("Door is open")
       state = "open"
       if state != oldstate:
            b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
            command =  {'transitiontime' : 0, 'on' : True, 'bri' : 254}
            b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', command)
       oldstate = "open"
       time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you said "check if the door is open or closed more frequent (like 0.1 seconds or something) and only call the hue lights whenever the status of the Door changes"

This should do it with a single variable and single sleep timer of `0.1` seconds for both door states

```
isClosed = False

while True:

    if GPIO.input(20):
        if !isClosed:
            isClosed = True
            print("Door is closed")
            b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
            b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', 'on', False)

    if GPIO.input(20) == False:
        if isClosed:
            isClosed = False
            print("Door is open")
            b.get_light('Nachttischlampe')
            command =  {'transitiontime' : 0, 'on' : True, 'bri' : 254}
            b.set_light('Nachttischlampe', command)

    time.sleep(0.1)
```